# In Adminpanel di.xml for graphql

Tags: magento2, php, xml, custom-attributes, installdata

Autosmart\CategoryAttributes\Model\Resolver\CategoryAttribute
                    resolve

Comment: hello @Noor Mohamed please check my answer

Comment: Please add more information.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try using Setup patch data

1. Create **CustomCategoryAttribute.php** at app/code/Autosmart/CategoryAttributes/Setup/Patch/Data and paste the below code :

   ```
   <?php

   namespace Autosmart\CategoryAttributes\Setup\Patch\Data;

   use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
   use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
   use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
   use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
   use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
   use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;

   class CustomCategoryAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
   {
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Category::ENTITY, 'enable_disable',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Enable/Disable',
                'input' => 'select',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 30,
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'General Information',
            ]
        );

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Category::ENTITY, 'custom_text',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Custom Text',
                'input' => 'textarea',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 30,
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'General Information',
            ]
        );

        $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(Category::ENTITY, 'enable_disable');
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(Category::ENTITY, 'custom_text');

        $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }
   }
   ```

2.create **category_form.xml** at app/code/Autosmart/CategoryAttributes/view/adminhtml/ui_component and paste the below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="enable_disable" sortOrder="100" formElement="select">
            <settings>
                <dataType>boolean</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Enable/Disable</label>
                <dataScope>enable_disable</dataScope>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <select>
                    <settings>
                        <options>
                            <option name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">No</item>
                            </option>
                            <option name="1" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Yes</item>
                            </option>
                        </options>
                    </settings>
                </select>
            </formElements>
        </field>
        <field name="custom_text" sortOrder="101" formElement="textarea">
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Custom Text</label>
                <dataScope>custom_text</dataScope>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <textarea>
                    <settings>
                        <!-- No initial value specified -->
                    </settings>
                </textarea>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

3. Now just execute this below command :
   **php bin/magento s:up**
   **php bin/magento s:s:d -f**
   **php bin/magento c:c**

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided code, it appears that you have correctly added custom category attributes to your Magento 2 installation. However, if the values entered in the admin panel are not being saved and the field shows empty, there might be a few possible causes and solutions to consider:

1. Clear cache: After making changes to attribute definitions or forms, it's important to clear the Magento cache. Run the following command from your Magento root directory: `php bin/magento cache:clean`.
2. Check attribute code: Ensure that the attribute codes used in both the InstallData.php file and category_form.xml file are correct and match each other. In your case, 'enable_disable' and 'custom_text' are used. Make sure these codes are consistent throughout.
3. Check database table: Verify that the attribute columns 'enable_disable' and 'custom_text' are present in the respective database tables. For categories, the table is typically `catalog_category_entity` and its corresponding value table. Ensure that the columns exist and have the correct data type.
4. Reindex: If the values are still not being saved, try reindexing your Magento indexes. Run the following command from your Magento root directory: `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`.
5. Log errors: Check your Magento logs for any relevant error messages. Enable the logging feature in your Magento configuration if it's not already enabled. Review the logs for any errors related to saving category attributes.

By following these steps, you should be able to troubleshoot and resolve the issue of custom category attribute values not being saved in the admin panel.